# Lektor CMS how to get related objects of a model instead of plain list?

Tags: python, lektor

I am using [Lektor CMS](http://getlektor.com) for my blog. I want to implement a categories functionality as said in [docs](https://www.getlektor.com/docs/guides/categories/). I have a `blog-post` model with `categories` field:

```
[fields.categories]
label = Категории
type = checkboxes
source = site.query('/categories')
```

As you notice, I'm using Russian language, so the category name maybe `Кодинг` and slug (directory name) may be `Coding`.

The problem is that when i access to the categories of blog-post I get plain list: `[u'Coding']` instead of list of objects which I can use to output the name in Russian and generate an url in English, something like `/blog/category/coding`.

I expect to be able to get such html:

```
{% for category in post.categories %}
    <a href="{{ category|url }}">{{ category.name }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

But it is not working. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% for category in post.categories %}
    {% set cat = pad.query('/blog/category').filter(F.name == category).first() %}
    <a href="{{ cat|url }}">{{ cat.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It looks like ugly hack for me, but i think it will work, thank you, accepting an answer!

Comment: There is currently no automatic mapping of values to queries/models so this is kinda the documented way :)